# Avg by Group in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have query and I want the average of each `Place_id`, but my query is returning a wrong output.

Is there something wrong in my query?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    place_id,
    SUM(fc.[main_percent_score]) aVG,
    CASE 
       WHEN fc.[main_percent_score] >= 0.00 AND fc.[main_percent_score] <= 0.99 
          THEN '0'
       WHEN fc.[main_percent_score] > 1.0 AND fc.[main_percent_score] <= 10.0 
          THEN '10'
       WHEN fc.[main_percent_score]  > 10.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 20.0 then  '20'
    when fc.[main_percent_score]  >20.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 30.0 then  '30'
    when fc.[main_percent_score]  >30.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 40.0 then  '40'
    when fc.[main_percent_score]  >40.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 50.0 then  '50'
    when fc.[main_percent_score]  >50.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 60.0 then  '60'
    when fc.[main_percent_score]  >60.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 70.0 then  '70'
    when fc.[main_percent_score]  >70.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 80.0 then  '80'
    when fc.[main_percent_score]  >80.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 90.0 then  '90'
    when fc.[main_percent_score]  >90.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 100.0 then  '100'
    end "PerTest" 
from [final scoring based on main] fc
group by case
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  >= 0.00 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 0.99 then  '0'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  > 1.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 10.0 then  '10'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  > 10.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 20.0 then  '20'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  >20.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 30.0 then  '30'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  >30.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 40.0 then  '40'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  >40.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 50.0 then  '50'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  >50.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 60.0 then  '60'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  >60.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 70.0 then  '70'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  >70.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 80.0 then  '80'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  >80.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 90.0 then  '90'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  >90.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 100.0 then  '100'
    end,
    place_id
ORDER BY
    place_id
```

The output of this query is:

```
2   10  10
2   20  20
```

I am expecting the result should be `b 30`

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: I'd use a derived table where I'd put that huge case expression, and then GROUP BY its result - to save some typing, and make the code more robust.

Comment: In your query you have `SUM` instead of `AVERAGE`.  Is that a typo?

Comment: still geeting same output

Answer (score 0):

can you try below and see :

```
select sum(aVG),sum(PerTest),place_id

from (

 select DISTINCT 
  place_id,
  sum(fc.[main_percent_score]) aVG,
  case
    when fc.[main_percent_score]  >= 0.00 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 0.99 
      then  '0'
    when fc.[main_percent_score]  > 1.0 and  fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 10.0 then  '10'
    when fc.[main_percent_score]  > 10.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 20.0 then  '20'
    when fc.[main_percent_score]  >20.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 30.0 then  '30'
    when fc.[main_percent_score]  >30.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 40.0 then  '40'
    when fc.[main_percent_score]  >40.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 50.0 then  '50'
    when fc.[main_percent_score]  >50.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 60.0 then  '60'
    when fc.[main_percent_score]  >60.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 70.0 then  '70'
    when fc.[main_percent_score]  >70.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 80.0 then  '80'
    when fc.[main_percent_score]  >80.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 90.0 then  '90'
    when fc.[main_percent_score]  >90.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 100.0 then  '100'
    end "PerTest" 
from [final scoring based on main] fc
group by case
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  >= 0.00 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 0.99 then  '0'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  > 1.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 10.0 then  '10'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  > 10.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 20.0 then  '20'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  >20.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 30.0 then  '30'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  >30.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 40.0 then  '40'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  >40.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 50.0 then  '50'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  >50.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 60.0 then  '60'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  >60.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 70.0 then  '70'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  >70.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 80.0 then  '80'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  >80.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 90.0 then  '90'
  when fc.[main_percent_score]  >90.0 and fc.[main_percent_score]  <= 100.0 then  '100'
  end,
  place_id
--order by place_id

) t

group by place_id
```